# ActiveAdmin in rails engine give me that error : uninitialized constant MyEngine::Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, rails-engines

I installed activeadmin in a rails engine that I mounted in my main application. When I try to access the home page I get the following error: uninitialized constant BackOffice::Admin

The code in lib/back_office/engine.rb

```
require 'devise'
require 'activeadmin'

module BackOffice
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace BackOffice

    initializer :back_office do
      ActiveAdmin.application.load_paths += Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/back_office/admin']
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
BackOffice::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, class_name: "BackOffice::AdminUser"
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

In the routes.rb file of my main app I have this :

```
mount BackOffice::Engine, at: "/back_office"
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: I think it is due to `solate_namespace BackOffice` 

Can you show me your back_office.gemspec and Gemfile of your engine?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Without `isolate_namespace BackOffice`, i have another error. I solved all issues by creating my engine with the full option and not the mountable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the error then got another one and so on. I solved all issues by creating my engine with the full option and not the mountable one.

Answer (score 0):

An uninitialized constant error would imply that it can't find BackOffice::Admin, so first -- is that constant defined in your engine? Or are you defining Admin under the `back_office` namespace without nesting it inside a BackOffice module parent? If you start a rails console and type `BackOffice::Admin`, is it able to resolve the class constant?

---

Does something like this work?

```rb
initializer :back_office do
  ActiveAdmin.application.load_paths << root.join('back_office/admin')
end
```

Try putting a binding in the initializer and validate that `root.join('back_office/admin')` is constructing the path you're expecting. You might also have to add a `before` or `after` argument to ensure that your action is running at the right time in ActiveAdmin's initialization flow.

---

If you run `bundle exec rails routes`, are the admin routes you're mounting namespaced correctly? Which route are you going to when you "try to access the homepage"? What feedback is is your app giving you in your development server logs?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I solved all issues by creating my engine with the full option and not the mountable one.